# Single particle space for the free Euclidean field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics

In Quantum Field Theory, the free field of mass $m$ can be constructed from creation and annihilation operators on the Fock space. Let $\mathscr{H}_1$ be the single-particle Hilbert space, $F(\mathscr{H}_2)$ be the Fock space, and $a^*$ and $a$ be the creation and annihilation operators. Then we have the Segal quantization
$$\theta(f) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a(f) + a^*)(f)).$$

To get the free quantum field of mass $m$, in the above construction we use the following single-particle space. Let
$$\mathscr{P} =
\{\sqrt{m^2 + p_0^2 + p_1^2 + p_2^2}, p_0, p_1, p_2\}
\subset \mathbb{R}^4$$ be the mass-$m$ hyperboloid in momentum space.
Let $f \in L_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$, and $\hat{f}$ be its Fourier transform. We construct the equivalence relation
$f \sim g \iff \hat{f}|_\mathscr{P} \equiv \hat{g}|_\mathscr{P}$.
Then the single-particle space $\mathscr{H}_1$ is the Hilbert space whose elements are these equivalence classes, and the scalar product is
$$\langle [f], [g] \rangle = \int_\mathscr{P} \hat{f}(p) \overline{\hat{g}(p)} d^4p.$$

Note that the above is a complex Hilbert space.

Now, I'm interested in a similar construction of the free Euclidean field of mass $m$. Using the same Segal quantization, I'd get a commuting field if I chose $\mathscr{H}_1$ to be a real Hilbert space. I've read the Sobolev space
[$W^{2, 2}(\mathbb{R}^4)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Multidimensional_case) - that is, with inner product
$\langle f, (-\Delta + 1)^{-1}g \rangle_{L_2}$ where $f$ and $g$ are four-dimensional generalized functions.

How can we derive that this is the single-particle space? Ideally, I'd prefer a derivation similar in style to the above, but I'm also interested in alternatives.

Comment: Euclidean in what sense?

Comment: @Qmechanic In the sense that their 2-point functions are analytic continuations of the 2-point Wightman functions of the Quantum fields. Alternatively, when viewed as random variables, they follow Nelson's axioms.